# Mth to last element

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, c++11

This is a challenge from [codeeval](https://www.codeeval.com/)

> Write a program which determines the Mth to the last element in a
> list.
>
> **Input sample:**
>
> The first argument is a path to a file. The file contains the series
> of space delimited characters followed by an integer. The integer
> represents an index in the list (1-based), one per line.
>
> For example:
> a b c d 4
>
> e f g h 2
>
> **Output sample:**
>
> Print to stdout the Mth element from the end of the list, one per
> line. If the index is larger than the number of elements in the list,
> ignore that input.
>
> For example:
> a
>
> g

Please let me know can I improve it.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<string>

void processRecords( const std::string& record )
{
     auto splitLoc= record.rfind(" ");
     std::string::size_type index = std::stoi( record.substr( splitLoc ) );
     std::string str( std::begin( record ), std::begin( record ) + splitLoc );
     str.erase( std::remove_if( str.begin(), str.end(), []( const char& val )
                                  { return std::isspace( val );}), str.end() );

     if( str.size() >= index )
     {
          std::cout << str[ str.size() - index ] << "\n";
     }
}

void readInputFile( const std::string fileName )
{
     std::ifstream infile( fileName );
     std::string record;

     while( std::getline( infile, record ) )
     {
         processRecords( record );
     }
     infile.close();
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    if( argc < 2 )
    {
        std::cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " input_file_name\n";
        exit( 0 );
    }

    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio( false );
    readInputFile( argv[ 1 ] );
}
```

Comment: Your `readProcessInputFile` violates both `Single Responsibility` and `Open/Closed` principles. You should really split it into 3 functions:
`read`, `findMth`, `display`

Comment: @DanielSokolov All suggestions for improvements belong in answers, not comments, even if it's that short.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `processRecords()` is a very generic name and doesn't say **what** is being done. A better name would be `displayMthLastItem()` (assuming you don't follow [Daniel Sokolov's advice](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/98182/mth-to-last-element#comment179789_98182) and split the function out further into the find and display operations).
- Spacing around function arguments is a little inconsistent:

  ```
  auto splitLoc= record.rfind(" ");  // NO SPACE
  std::string::size_type index = std::stoi( record.substr( splitLoc ) );  // HAS SPACE
  ```
- `index` has type `std::string::size_type`. This is generally only needed when indexing into a `std::string`. The problem definition says that it's an integer, so either declare it as an `int` or, since you're using C++11, as `auto` (which will be deduced to `int` as the return type of [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).
- As presented, the input data set has a blank line; your code will crash because the [`string::rfind()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rfind) call will return [`string::npos`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos) if it can't find the search string. Add a check for that value:

  ```
  void processRecords( const std::string& record )
  {
       auto splitLoc= record.rfind(" ");
       if( splitLoc != std::string::npos )
       {
            // ... the rest of the function goes here...
       }
  }
  ```
- Function `readInputFile()` takes its argument by value; change it to a reference-to-const to prevent copies being made of its argument:

  ```
  void readInputFile( const std::string& fileName )  // "string&", not "string"
  ```
- You don't need to call `std::ifstream::close()` at the end of `readInputFile()`: the destructor will close the file for you as soon as `infile` goes out of scope when the function returns.